# If only single quote is passed as parameter in ajax post it throws error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The JQuery Code:

```
var name = jQuery("#name1").val();
jQuery.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + 'search/ind',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { name: name, },
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery('#input').val('');
    }
});
```

If only a "'" (single quote is given for search field) , the result is getting at response but due to a JS error it is preventing from appending to html container.

The ERROR:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
...imit":14,"keyword":{"name":"'"
```

Any help is appreciated as

SOLUTION:

The main reason behind this issue was due to json parsing.... after debugging through code i was able to find the issue and on removing an unwanted parsing the params are getting correctly.Anyway thanks to all who assisted in finding this issue...cheers!!!

Comment: The error is for the useless comma in `data: { name: name, }`

Comment: Actually there are more fields after name and final field is not having any comma.

Comment: A fiddle will be best in this situation to explain your problem. Clearly there is nothing wrong in Ajax statement. It must be some other syntax error which you might be committing.

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove Extra Comma from  `data: { name: name, },` and try Again

```
var name = jQuery("#name1").val();
jQuery.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + 'search/ind',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { name: name },      /*Extra Comma removed*/
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery('#input').val('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use short hands and put the key of the object in quotes "", it is just simple and easy to read.

```
var name = $( '#name1' ).val();

$.post( siteUrl + 'search/ind', { "name" : name }, function( response ) {

          $( '#input' ).val('');
    }
});
```